# Potential new class of probability distributions - where to confirm (and publish)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian, economics, publishing

I think I may have found a new class of probability distributions on the unit interval. This class is a conjugate family (with an intuitive but nonstandard notion of "conjugate" that's conceptually related to the regular one). I need this class for a model in a paper on an applied topic, but it could be of broader use to statisticians and economists. This class is not that difficult to derive (once you know what you're looking at), requiring nothing but high school algebra and a little bit of calculus, which is why I am almost certain that someone discovered it a million years ago - but I have no idea where to look!

The questions are as follows -

1) How to confirm that no one else discovered this, or find its name? Is there an up to date catalog somewhere?

2) In the unlikely case that it is a novelty, which journal would be appropriate, given that it's not a "hard" discovery, but potentially broadly useful (targeting economists and statisticians)?

Comment: you could check books of statistics , there are lots of distributions of probability there :) to check if yours is new. To publish look for a 'journal of statistics' or put in wikipedia with a link or your own

Comment: You may not find it already exists for some time.  I once wrote about distributions with a ["shape memorylessness"](http://www.se16.info/hgb/shape-memoryless.pdf) property where the continuous examples were exponential distributions and special cases of the beta and beta prime distributions.  I never found a good name for the particular beta distributions beyond ["stretched reverse power function distribution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Beta_distribution#The_name_of_a_special_case?) but 8 years later I found the beta prime cases were called Lomax distributions

Comment: have you looked in Johnson and Kotz?

Comment: I have looked at some papers and catalogs online, but no, it seems uncommon. Will have to check out the library, as suggested.